# Vertically connect columns Materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, materialize

[image]

I have a materializeCSS grid here and I need to pull blocks to each other vertically so if my blocks are of different size, they will 'stack' to each other
Can't find any solution on the web, is it actually possible?

My code:

```
 <div class="news row">
            <div class="newsItem__wrap col s12 m6 l4 xl4">
               <div class="news__item newsItem">
                <img src="{{asset('images/cat.jpg')}}" alt="" class="newsItem__img">
                    <h2 class="newsItem__title">В Киеве разоблачили группу "черных риелторов"</h2>
                    <p class="newsItem__subtitle">Они по сговору проворачивали аферы, чтобы завладеть…</p>
                    <div class="newsItem__info newsInfo">
                        <span class="newsInfo__time">5 минут назад</span>
                        <div class="newsInfo__views views">
                            <img src="{{asset('images/comment.svg')}}" alt="" class="views__img">
                            <span class="views__count">15</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code please? If you have time put code with example

Comment: You can't do this without masonry.js. What you can do is fix the height of the card for consistency. I have a snippet I can share if it's useful..?

Comment: The core thing is to make them collapse vertically without fix height

Comment: You can't do this without masonry....

Comment: https://masonry.desandro.com/